If $I$ is a non-finitely generated injective module over $A$, can we obtain a decomposition $I \cong \prod_{i=1}^n \big( D((Ae_i)^*) \big)^{t_i}?$
Let $A$ be a finite-dimensional algebra over a field $k$. Then any projective module $P$ (not necessarily finitely generated) over $A$ has the following isomorphism:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{isomorphism}
P \cong (Ae_1)^{(m_1)} \oplus (Ae_2)^{(m_2)} \oplus \cdots \oplus (Ae_n)^{(m_n)},
\end{equation}
where $\{e_i\}_{1 \leqslant i \leqslant n}$ is a basic set of primitive idempotents for $A$. Since any finite-dimensional algebra is a semiperfect ring, the above isomorphism \eqref{isomorphism} can be deduced from Theorem 27.11 on page 306 of the book Rings and Categories of Modules.
If $I$ is a finitely generated injective module over $A$, then we can similarly write an isomorphism:
$$
I \cong \prod_{i=1}^n \big( D((Ae_i)^*) \big)^{l_i},
$$
where $*$ and $D$ denote the functors $\operatorname{Hom}_A(-, _A\!A)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_k(-, k)$, respectively.

My question is:

If $I$ is a non-finitely generated injective module over $A$, can we also obtain a similar decomposition as for projective modules:
$$
I \cong \prod_{i=1}^n \big( D((Ae_i)^*) \big)^{t_i}?
$$
